# Can I have as a function parameter a dictionary containing array values?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm creating a function within a class that has a 2 parameters: a string and a dictionary. I'm very new to swift so I don't know if I can have an array as a value to a key in a dictionary. Can I?

I have been able to query the dictionary but I can't seem to include it as a parameter within a function

```
    func fileSizePerDiscipline(_ discipline: String, models: Dictionary<String,[Any]>) -> Int{
        var filteredArray = [Any]()
        var total: Int = 0
        for (filename, info) in models {
            var pairing = [Any]()
            var testdiscipline = info[0]
            var filesize = info[1]
            if testdiscipline == discipline {
                total += filesize
            }
        }
        return total
    }
}
//The dictionary I am working with
var cdModels = ["facade.rvt": ["Architecture",200,"001"],
                "foundation.rvt": ["Structural",450,"010"],
                "site.rvt": ["Civil",1000,"003"],
                "basebuilding.rvt": ["Architecture",250,"001"],
                "framework.rvt": ["Structural",350,"016"]
]
```

I am trying to get the total size of files associated with a particular discipline. For instance total size of architecture files.

Comment: Yes you can. Which part are you facing an issue with? What do you mean by `I can't seem to include it as a parameter within a function`

Comment: Also, note that your value array is set as `Any`. So you can't just index the value and use it, you'll have to typecast it into String or Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely pass it as a parameter.  note that your value array is set as Any. So you can't just index the value and use it, you'll have to typecast it into String or Int.

```
for (filename, info) in models {
     var pairing = [Any]()
     var testdiscipline = info[0] as? String ?? ""
     var filesize = info[1] as? Int ?? 0
     if testdiscipline == discipline {
         total += filesize
    }
}
```

I'm just utilising `??` and using empty values instead, you might want to change that to fit your needs.